# Como utilizar um botão de um fragment

Tags: android

Tenho um botão no meu fragment

**fragment_main**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/fragMain"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
tools:context="makerapp.android.minhastarefas.MainActivity.ListItensFragment">



<!-- Exibe nome da lista atual -->
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp">

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/stringVolta"
            android:id="@+id/anterior" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>


<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="@color/md_grey_300"/>

<!-- Lista de itens -->
<makerapp.android.minhastarefas.ui.DynamicListView
    android:id="@+id/itens_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:divider="@color/md_grey_300"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="true"/>

<!-- Layout a ser exibido quando a lista estiver vazia -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:drawablePadding="16dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_empty_list"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/empty_list_text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_color"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

</FrameLayout>

<!-- Layout destinado a publicidade-->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/ad_framelayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/ad_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

e to querendo acessar este botão na classe MainActivity

**MainActivity**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btAnterior = (Button)findViewById(R.id.anterior);

    btAnterior.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("TAG","ta aki");
        }
    });
}
```

Deste jeito ai está dando este erro.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{makerapp.android.minhastarefas/makerapp.android.minhastarefas.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Como faço para pegar o evento de click neste botão nesta classe?

Comment: Você pode pegar esse evento dentro `Fragment`, após inflar o layout, e notificar sua `Activity`.

Comment: eu ate consegui usar dentro do Fragment mais eu precisava de um método desta classe ai quando tentei usar assim  MainActivity main = new MainActivity();   main.metodo() , deu erro porque algumas variáveis usadas neste método são iniciadas no oncreate

Comment: Assim não vai funcionar, nunca instancie uma `Activity`, o Android já faz isso e gerencia o ciclo de vida. Use o padrão Observer para notificar a `Activity`, vou criar uma resposta.

Comment: ta bom ........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para notificar a `Activity` de forma a não ter mais acoplamento, use o padrão **Observer/Listener**.

#### 1. Crie uma interface que tenha todos os eventos que podem ocorrer no `Fragment` e que dependam de outra(s) classe(s).

```
public interface FragmentListener {
    public void metodo(); // Metodo que sera chamado
}
```

#### 2. Implemente a interface na sua `Activity` ou qualquer outra classe que queira usar:

```
public SuaActivity extends Activity implements FragmentListener {
    @Override
    public void metodo() {
        // Implementação
    }
}
```

#### 3. Crie uma propriedade para guardar um objeto que implemente essa interface no seu `Fragment`:

```
public class SeuFragment extends Fragment {
    private FragmentListener mListener;

    // Getters e Setters omitidos
}
```

#### 4. Use a interface quando o botão for clicado:

```
btAnterior.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(mListener != null) mListener.metodo();
    }
});
```

#### 5. Passe a implementação dessa interface para o `Fragment`:

```
// Se a Activity implementar, voce pode usar o metodo onAttach do Fragment para setar
public void onAttach(Activity a) {
    super.onAttach(a);

    if(a instanceof FragmentListener) {
        mListener = (FragmentListener) a;
    }
}

// Ou com um setter
public void setFragmentListener(FragmentListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}
```

#### 6. Libere a instância da interface quando o `Fragment` for destruído, assim evitando Memory Leak:

```
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mListener = null;
}

// ou
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    mListener = null;
}

// ou quando for dettached
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}
```

Comment: não entendi o mListener do item 5

Comment: O `mListener` é o atributo `listener`, vou editar.

Comment: depois que perguntei percebi kkk , Funcionou muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

você pode expor o btAnterior da seguinte forma.
No seu fragmento você pode escrever algo do genero:

```
private View view;
private TextView btAnterior;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    this.view = inflater.inflate(...);
    this.btAnterior = (Button)findViewById(R.id.anterior);
    ...
}

public TextView getBtAnterior() {
    return this.btAnterior;
}
```

Na sua MainActivity, você poder acessar o btAnterior do seguinte modo:

```
private SparseArray<Fragment> fragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();
private ListItensFragment fragmentListItens;

@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
    this.fragments.put(fragment.getId(), fragment);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    this.fragmentListItens = (ListItensFragment)this.fragments.get(R.id.fragmentListItens);
    this.fragmentListItens.getBtAnterior().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("TAG","ta aki");
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Só pra atualizar caso alguém mais necessite. Eu resolvi esse problema fazendo assim:

Dentro da classe do fragmente( antes):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dom, container, false);
}
```

Dentro da classe do fragmente( Depois):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dom, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.ID_ListView_test);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}
```

Eu pego o que é retornado por padrão da classe do fragment e jogo em uma variável "view". E utilizo essa variável pra acessar os métodos que eu teria em uma classe de uma activity, como o findViewById. No caso do Botão, você faz a mesma coisa que fiz com o listview e depois usa o bt.setOnClickListner normal como se estivesse em uma activity. Não sei se é o correto, mas foi o que funcionou pra mim.