# Android Studio Clicar eu um botão dentro de um Fragment

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment, button

Olá,

Preciso acionar o evento click de um botão que está dentro de um `Fragment`.

Eu estava seguindo a resposta [deste artigo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49445/como-utilizar-um-bot%C3%A3o-de-um-fragment), mas (desculpem minha ignorância) ficou muito complicado para eu entender, pois o autor da resposta diz para criarmos isto, criarmos aquilo, mas não diz onde: se dentro do `Fragment` ou dentro da `MainActivity` ou dentro da própria Interface, enfim...

Chegou uma hora que em que me perdi na explicação.

Meu projeto segue o seguinte padrão:

**A Activity principal:**

```
<RelativeLayout
...
>
    <LinearLayout
      ...
        >

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
         ...>

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
             ... />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
             ... />
        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
         ...
            >
        </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Então dentro do `Fragment` do Usuário tem um botão de cadastrar (`btnCadUser`).

Pois bem... Criei a Interface, Implementei na `MainActivity`, criei os métodos, mas não estou conseguindo criar o evento click do botão e nem instanciar os `EditText` de dentro do `Fragment`...

Sempre me retorna referência nula, por exemplo:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Obrigado muitíssimo a quem puder explicar ou que tenha um passo a passo, pois os vídeos e artigos que tenho encontrado na internet presumem que o leitor já é um crânio em desenvolvimento Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Senhores(as)

Resolvi minha questão.

O que funcionou para mim não foi criar Interface, nem Implementar nada, nem criar métodos dentro da Interface. **A Interface é importante sim, mas não precisei dela neste caso**.

O que precisei fazer foi:

Dentro do `onCreateView` do meu **`Fragment`** (não da MainActivity):

- "Inflar" o Fragmento como uma View;
- Depois, declarar os objetos (botão, EditTexts, etc);
- Depois, declarar o `setOnClickListener` do meu botão de cadastrar;
- Depois retornar o `Fragment`, que chamei de `fragmentoUsuario`

como mostrado abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É isso. Espero que ajude a outros com o mesmo problema!